# Split column based on another column value to prepare data for one-way Anova

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'd like to split the values in one column based on the ones in another column, as in this example:

| Group | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Group 1 | 7 |
| Group 1 | 4 |
| Group 1 | 9 |
| Group 2 | 1 |
| Group 2 | 8 |
| Group 2 | 1 |
| Group 2 | 5 |
| Group 2 | 3 |
| Group 3 | 6 |
| Group 3 | 10 |
| Group 3 | 5 |
| Group 3 | 4 |

Desired result:

| Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 1 | 6 |
| 4 | 8 | 10 |
| 9 | 1 | 5 |
|  | 5 | 4 |
|  | 3 |  |

I have a table with a lot of data and I would like to perform One-way Anova on it, but AFAIK Anova requires to have data on grouped adjacent columns.
Is there any way to achieve this in some automatic way? If possible, having the opportunity to choose the group and value columns when I have more than two.

Thanks!

Comment: You can do this easily in Power Query, if that is an option.

Comment: Care to explain how?

Comment: See my posted answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Power Query Solution, given your data
*If you will be doing this repetively, with differing numbers of values in the groups, the M-code may need to be edited, if you don't get the results you expect*

- Get Data => from table/range
- Group By `Group`   Operation `All Rows`

[image]

- Add Column => Custom Column => Formula: `=Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")`

[image]

- Select the double arrow at the top of the custom column and `Extract Values` using a semicolon as the delimiter
- Split the custom column by delimiter (semicolon)
- Transpose the table and Use First Row as Headers

**M Code** generated by the above steps:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table20"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Group", type text}, {"Value", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Group"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Group=nullable text, Value=nullable number]}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")),
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom", {"Custom", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), {"Custom.1", "Custom.2", "Custom.3", "Custom.4", "Custom.5"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Split Column by Delimiter"),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Transposed Table", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Group 1", Int64.Type}, {"Group 2", Int64.Type}, {"Group 3", Int64.Type}})
in
    #"Changed Type1"
```

**Data & Results**

### [image]

Answer (score 0):

Supposing your data is in columns A and B in sheet1:

- enter this formula in A1 in a new sheet :
  `=TRANSPOSE (UNIQUE(FILTER(Sheet1!A:A, ROW(Sheet1!A:A) <>1))`
- and this formula to A2:
  `=FILTER(Sheet1$B:$B,sheet1!$A:$A=A$1)`
  Copy it to additional columns as necessary

This will work on in office 365,not in previous versions

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately I need something doable in Excel 2019